# select specific key value from json in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i have this codes in my test.php that ajax send request from index.php to this page.in this page i created an array and convert it to json and returned it finally:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
"status"=>200,
"result"=>array(
    "winner"=>"unknown",
    "options"=>array(
        "1"=>"first",
        "2"=>"second"
    ),"question"=>"are u ok?",
    "answer"=>"1"
)
);
$jsonArr = json_encode($arr);
echo $jsonArr;
?>
```

and in index.php i send request to test.php via ajax and i receive json . my problem is how can i alert just for example question from receive json from test.php.it alerts undefined

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'test.php',
    data:{},
    success:(function (response) {
    var x = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        alert(x."question");
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `x."question"` to `x.result.question`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I just noticed. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `x."question"` to `x.result["question"]`, or `x.result.question`.

Everything is an object in JavaScript. You can dereference *any* object in JavaScript by using `[]`(bracket) notation. If there are no special characters in the name, you can omit the brackets and string and just do `object.property`. Let's create an example.

```js
let response = JSON.stringify({
  status: 200,
  result: {
    winner: "unknown",
    options: {
      "1": "first",
      "2": "second"
    },
    question: "are u ok?",
    answer: 1
  }
}); // Now response is almost exactly what you get from the server

console.log(response);

let x = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(x.result.question);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of `response`?

Comment: Okay, check it out now.

Comment: tnx a lot . but there is another little problem. i want to alert option 1 alert(x.result.options.1).could you guide me?im new comer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156784/discussion-between-aanand-kainth-and-sepehr).